# Reading a size of text file from inside sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to create a text file from some data from the sql server tables. I have created the query for that.

Once the file is created I also have to create a trigger file or just another text file with some infos like number of rows, file date, name etc. Apart from these this trigger file has to have the file size information.

I think I figured out that I will create a trigger table and keep updating it with the other info like number of rows, file name , date as i collect my data in data collection query. But I am confused about how to get the file size for my trigger file from inside my query.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: It's usually very difficult to work with files or anything else outside the database using TSQL, because it's a data manipulation language, not a general-purpose programming language. I suggest you consider writing an external script or application that manages the files and updates the database with the file size data, it will almost certainly be easier than using TSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the inputs. I ended up creating a .net executable which would go read the file size and update the database for that.

Comment: yeah, i think it is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use Powershell to carry out tasks that need to interact with Windows, but it is not very interesting is it.

There are two SQL based solutions I can think of:

**xp_cmdshell**

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\temp\test.txt'

  Output
  Volume in drive C is System
  Volume Serial Number is A227-BF7F
  NULL
  Directory of c:\temp
  NULL
  26/04/2013  10:52 AM                20 test.txt
                1 File(s)             20 bytes
                0 Dir(s)  214,210,105,344 bytes free
  NULL
```

There are couple of drawbacks though:

1. xp_cmdshell is switched off by default. (Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
   SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'xp_cmdshell', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.)
2. You will need to parse the output.

**openrowset**

```
select datalength(bulkcolumn) from openrowset(bulk 'c:\temp\test.txt', single_clob) a
```

Assuming it is text file and you don't really need the exact number reported by the operating system, you can just count the number of bytes contained in your text file.

Hope that will give you some ideas.